# access jmeter.log file when lunching test from jenkins jmeter.log (Permission denied) java.io.FileNotFoundException: error

Tags: linux, jenkins, jmeter

when using jmeter from linux command line it works perfectly. with this command, inside jmeter/bin folder:

```
 ./jmeter.sh -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml -n -t /etc/tomcat/Catalina/parser/test.jmx -l  /etc/tomcat/Catalina/parser/testres.jtl
```

it creats testres.jtl file.

but i have problem when trying to lunch this command from jenkins:

i have created new project and added: add build step--> Execute Shell
inside shell is:

```
cd /opt/jmeter/bin

./jmeter.sh -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml -n -t /etc/tomcat/Catalina/parser/test.jmx -l  /etc/tomcat/Catalina/parser/testres.jtl
```

but when lunching inside console output is errors:

```
2018-05-30 12:07:02,990 main ERROR FileManager (jmeter.log) java.io.FileNotFoundException: jmeter.log (Permission denied) java.io.FileNotFoundException: jmeter.log (Permission denied)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.FileManager$FileManagerFactory.createManager(FileManager.java:422)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.FileManager$FileManagerFactory.createManager(FileManager.java:406)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AbstractManager.getManager(AbstractManager.java:113)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.OutputStreamManager.getManager(OutputStreamManager.java:115)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.FileManager.getFileManager(FileManager.java:180)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.FileAppender$Builder.build(FileAppender.java:95)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.FileAppender$Builder.build(FileAppender.java:51)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginBuilder.build(PluginBuilder.java:122)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createPluginObject(AbstractConfiguration.java:958)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:898)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:890)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.doConfigure(AbstractConfiguration.java:513)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.initialize(AbstractConfiguration.java:237)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.start(AbstractConfiguration.java:249)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.setConfiguration(LoggerContext.java:545)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:617)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:634)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.start(LoggerContext.java:229)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:153)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:45)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getContext(LogManager.java:194)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLoggerAdapter.getContext(AbstractLoggerAdapter.java:122)
    at org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getContext(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:43)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLoggerAdapter.getLogger(AbstractLoggerAdapter.java:46)
    at org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:29)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:358)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:383)
    at org.apache.jmeter.JMeter.<clinit>(JMeter.java:110)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
    at org.apache.jmeter.NewDriver.main(NewDriver.java:243)

2018-05-30 12:07:03,002 main ERROR Could not create plugin of type class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.FileAppender for element File: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ManagerFactory [org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.FileManager$FileManagerFactory@65d6b83b] unable to create manager for [jmeter.log] with data [org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.FileManager$FactoryData@d706f19] java.lang.IllegalStateException: ManagerFactory [org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.FileManager$FileManagerFactory@65d6b83b] unable to create manager for [jmeter.log] with data [org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.FileManager$FactoryData@d706f19]
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AbstractManager.getManager(AbstractManager.java:115)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.OutputStreamManager.getManager(OutputStreamManager.java:115)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.FileManager.getFileManager(FileManager.java:180)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.FileAppender$Builder.build(FileAppender.java:95)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.FileAppender$Builder.build(FileAppender.java:51)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginBuilder.build(PluginBuilder.java:122)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createPluginObject(AbstractConfiguration.java:958)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:898)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:890)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.doConfigure(AbstractConfiguration.java:513)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.initialize(AbstractConfiguration.java:237)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.start(AbstractConfiguration.java:249)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.setConfiguration(LoggerContext.java:545)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:617)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:634)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.start(LoggerContext.java:229)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:153)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:45)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getContext(LogManager.java:194)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLoggerAdapter.getContext(AbstractLoggerAdapter.java:122)
    at org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getContext(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:43)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLoggerAdapter.getLogger(AbstractLoggerAdapter.java:46)
    at org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:29)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:358)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:383)
    at org.apache.jmeter.JMeter.<clinit>(JMeter.java:110)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
    at org.apache.jmeter.NewDriver.main(NewDriver.java:243)

2018-05-30 12:07:03,007 main ERROR Unable to invoke factory method in class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.FileAppender for element File: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No factory method found for class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.FileAppender java.lang.IllegalStateException: No factory method found for class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.FileAppender
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginBuilder.findFactoryMethod(PluginBuilder.java:229)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginBuilder.build(PluginBuilder.java:134)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createPluginObject(AbstractConfiguration.java:958)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:898)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:890)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.doConfigure(AbstractConfiguration.java:513)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.initialize(AbstractConfiguration.java:237)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.start(AbstractConfiguration.java:249)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.setConfiguration(LoggerContext.java:545)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:617)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:634)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.start(LoggerContext.java:229)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:153)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:45)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getContext(LogManager.java:194)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLoggerAdapter.getContext(AbstractLoggerAdapter.java:122)
    at org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getContext(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:43)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLoggerAdapter.getLogger(AbstractLoggerAdapter.java:46)
    at org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:29)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:358)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:383)
    at org.apache.jmeter.JMeter.<clinit>(JMeter.java:110)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
    at org.apache.jmeter.NewDriver.main(NewDriver.java:243)
```

this is my part from log4j2.xml

```
<Appenders>

    <File name="jmeter-log" fileName="${sys:jmeter.logfile:-jmeter.log}" append="false">
      <PatternLayout>
        <pattern>%d %p %c{1.}: %m%n</pattern>
      </PatternLayout>
    </File>

    <GuiLogEvent name="gui-log-event">
      <PatternLayout>
        <pattern>%d %p %c{1.}: %m%n</pattern>
      </PatternLayout>
    </GuiLogEvent>

  </Appenders>
```

i just moved this project on linux, before was on Win and there wasn't this error.

what can be reason and how can i fix it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can see 2 options:

1. Give the `jenkins` user (or whatever account Jenkins is running with) ownership to `/opt/jmeter` folder using [chown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chown) command like:

   ```
   chown -R jenkins /opt/jmeter
   ```
2. Configure JMeter to store logs into location where Jenkins has write access too, i.e. `/tmp`,  change this line:

   ```
   <File name="jmeter-log" fileName="${sys:jmeter.logfile:-jmeter.log}" append="false">
   ```

   to this one

   ```
   <File name="jmeter-log" fileName="/tmp/jmeter.log" append="false">
   ```

   See [How to Configure JMeter Logging](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging) article for more details.

Comment: Great, thank you, worked both suggestions, log folder moved to my working log folder and gave grant to jenkins user.

Answer (score 0):

You have to launch jmeter from a directory where file writing acces is allowed.

On windows I added the "...\jmeter\bin" to my PATH system variable and created the JMETER_HOME system variable to point to "...\jmeter" (no bin). I then just launch jmeter from any directory with write access without this warning. jmeter.log will be created in the startup directory. You don't have to modify jmeter's log4j configuration for this to work or to give access to installation folder.